# How to get only one value from group of duplicate names using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have same names more than one but different locations,ages,messages for same names so i want to get only unique name with different locations,ages,messages using php mysql 
Here's my code

```
Name         locations    ages          messages 
myusername    USA          25     getting duplicate username
myusername    Uk           26     getting duplicate username1
myusername    india        28     getting duplicate username2
mypassword    india        26      getting duplicate username3
mypassword1   USA          29      getting duplicate username4
```

in this i want to get only one values with unique names using php mysql here's the example

```
      Name         locations     ages          messages 
    myusername       USA          25     getting duplicate username
    mypassword1      USA          29      getting duplicate username4
```

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you can use

```
select * from `table` group by name
```

Comment: @user3396954 if it is the solution to your question, you should accept them.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:-**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```